# How to mock a call to a base method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

**tldr;** How do I mock a call to a base method (using moq)?

I need to find a way to either workaround a problem regarding mocking a method that belongs to the class I inherit from, or to actually be able to just mock it.

I will start by posting some code:

The code to test:

```
public class CustomProductListingService : ProductListingService
{
    public override IEnumerable<Product> ListAllProducts(ICategory category)
    {
        //does some internal filtering and to the developer unkown magic..
        //would like to mock the result of this call..
        var baseResult = base.ListAllProducts(category);

        if(category.Name.StartsWith("A"))
            return baseResult.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A"));
        else if(category.Name.StartsWith("B"))
            return baseResult.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("B"));
        else
            return baseResult;
    }
}
```

The test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CustomProductListingService_ShouldOnlyReturnProductsWithNameStartingWithA() 
{
    //arrange
    var customProductListingService = new CustomProductListingService();
    ICategory category = new category
    {
        Name = "Abcd"
    };

    //act
    var result = customProductListingService.ListAllProducts(category);

    //assert
    foreach(var product in result)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(product.StartsWith("A"));
    }
}
```

as you can see I call base.ListAllProducts from within my own implementation of ListAllProducts, now what I would like to be able to do is to mock base.ListAllProducts since I really dont care about what that method does internally and want to be able to control the outcome(return) so I can test my own implementation.

However, there is also another issue, this code is all a part of an implementation for an existing system, where the system normally would just inject the ProductListingService using a DI, but in my case I needed some custom behaviour and thats why the CustomProductListingService exists. What I have basically done then is to override the default registration of the system for ProductListingService and instead told it to inject my custom class CustomProductListingService.
In this case the DI-framework used is StructureMap, so basically the resultning container registration would end up looking something like:

```
            var container = new Container(c =>
            {
                //use system implementation
                c.For<ProductListingService>().Use<ProductListingService>();
                //override system with my implementation
                c.For<ProductListingService>().Use<CustomProductListingService>();
            });
```

This then causes a problem where I cant simply do this:

```
public class CustomProductListingService : ProductListingService
{
    private readonly ProductListingService _productListingService;

    public CustomProductListingService(ProductListingService productListingService)
    {
        this._productListingService = productListingService;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Product> ListAllProducts(ICategory category)
    {
        //does some internal filtering and to the developer unkown magic..
        //would like to mock the result of this call..
        var baseResult = this._productListingService.ListAllProducts(category);

        if(category.Name.StartWith("A"))
            return baseResult.Where(p => p.Name.StartWith("A"));
        else if(category.Name.StartWith("B"))
            return baseResult.Where(p => p.Name.StartWith("B"));
        else
            return baseResult;
    }
}
```

Since that would cause a circular dependency and would be sort of strange to inject an instance thats the same type as the class I inherit from. (If this was possible I could simply mock the instance thats passed as a parameter to the constructor).

Any ideas of how to get around this?
Should probably add that the mocking-framework Im using is Moq, if that somehow makes this easier to solve.

Comment: How does `ProductListingService` look like? Is is implementing any interfaces? It isn't clear, why are you using real implementation `CustomProductListingService` in a test

Comment: In this this particular case I have to inherit from ProductListingService since thats whats registred in the systems DI-container. So I guess that even if we could implement from a different interface, or some other class, then we wouldnt be able to override the implementation used by the system.
The use of the implementation of CustomProductListingService is since I want to test the actualt implementation of ListAllProducts, I could mock CustomProductListingService and use "CallBase" in Moq, but the result would be the same

Comment: Can you refactor and extract the code that "does some internal filtering and to the developer unknown magic" into a separate class and pass it in as a dependency, then mock that? Sounds like the class is already to big; smaller classes should be preferred anyway.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, since the system might update its internal code, this is not a path I would prefer to go down, but yes, it could maybe be a way of doing it (Should probably add that the systems implementation code is not "publicly" available, so would have to be decompiled and then implemented)

Comment: @Inx51 yes, my further suggestion was to use `CallBase = true`. Another option is to refactor your code a little bit, and extract an interfaces. Moq also allows to call `protected` methods

Comment: Oh, I see - you're inheriting from 3rd party code (sry, didn't read carefully enough). If you have to keep the inheritance, then you can do a variant of what you tried at the end. The simplest thing is to pass a lambda as a dependency to your class; e.g. `CustomProductListingService(Func<ProductListingService, ICategory, IEnumerable<Product>> productLister)`. Then you can do `var baseResult = productLister(this, category)`. Pass `(pls, cat) => pls.ListAllProducts(cat)` in production, and `(pls, cat) => mock.ListAllProducts(cat)` when mocking.

Comment: Or you can do something more involved with a factory method that returns an instance of a role interface (instead of just the single-purpose lambda dependency) and a wrapper over the ProductListingService that implements that interface (same overall idea).

Comment: Sorry, just realized that's not going to cut it. I guess I need more coffee :) There is a way to make it work, but it's quite a bit uglier`. See [here](https://repl.it/repls/GrippingSkyblueSyntax). Essentially, you'd use some kind of a forwarding function (or an object).